# Always on top of a full-screen app?

Tags: menu, title-bar

An editor (notepadqq) is opened in a full screen mode. I need a calculator app (SpeedCrunch) to be always visible on top of the editor in the same workspace. When I set the calc to be 'always on top' via its title bar menu - it disappears anyway when I focus on the editor window. Is there a way to resolve that? Thanks a lot.

And one more thing - the title bar menu always pops up upon a right click on a freshly opened window's title bar, but if I tick 'always on top' and want to open title bar menu again - it doesn't pop up anymore upon the first click. It needs 20-30 clicks on a title bar and then, sometimes, it pops up again...

Answer (score 0):

Try checking `Settings` > `Behavior` > `Always on Top`, then restart SpeedCrunch. After restart it should stay on top of any other apps, including maximized ones.
(Tested on elementary OS 5.0 Juno, SpeedCrunch 0.12)